# Cuda Parallelized Kernel Shared Counter Variable

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cuda, numba

Is there a way to have an integer counter variable that can be incremented/decremented across all threads in a parallelized cuda kernel? The below code outputs "[1]" since the modifications to the counter array from one thread is not applied in the others.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda


@cuda.jit('void(int32[:])')
def func(counter):
    counter[0] = counter[0] + 1


counter = cuda.to_device(np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int32))
threadsperblock = 64
blockspergrid = 18
func[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](counter)
print(counter.copy_to_host())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [numba cuda atomics](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/intrinsics.html):

```
$ cat t18.py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda


@cuda.jit('void(int32[:])')
def func(counter):
    cuda.atomic.add(counter, 0, 1)


counter = cuda.to_device(np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int32))
threadsperblock = 64
blockspergrid = 18
print blockspergrid * threadsperblock
func[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](counter)
print(counter.copy_to_host())
$ python t18.py
1152
[1152]
$
```

An [atomic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-modify-write) performs an indivisible read-modify-write operation on the target, so threads do not interfere with each other when they update the target variable.

Certainly other methods are possible, depending on your actual needs, such as a [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).  numba provides some [reduction sugar](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/reduction.html) also.

Comment: Is there a way to read the current value of the counter from one of the threads?

Comment: sure, perhaps you should read the first (documentation) link I provided?  It says "Returns the old value at the index location as if it is loaded atomically."  So you could just do `i = cuda.atomic.add(counter, 0, 1)`.  Or if you just want to read it somewhere else, you could do `i = counter[0]`, just like reading any variable passed to a numba ufunc

Comment: Ah, must have missed that detail. Reading with counter[0] from inside the kernel doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll get some number.  You may not get the number you were expecting, but that is a function of the CUDA execution model and memory model.  There is no defined order of execution.  Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the operation done by one thread in global memory is visible to another thread, unless you take steps to make it so, such as using atomics, or a memory fence function, or the like.  CUDA has a "weakly ordered memory model" when viewed from the standpoint of independent threads.